# How to stop user from pressing enter before entering a value?

Tags: c#, .net, console, calculator

I am building a console calculator program that requires a user to input two values to do a mathematical operation to. The application is pretty well rounded but I wanted to limit the ability to skip inputting a number.

```
Console.WriteLine("Insert a number for value 1: ");
string value1 = "0"; 
ConsoleKeyInfo key;

do
{
    key = Console.ReadKey(true);
    if (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Backspace)
    {
        double val = 0;
        bool _x = double.TryParse(key.KeyChar.ToString(), out val);
        if (_x)
        {
            value1 += key.KeyChar;
            Console.Write(key.KeyChar);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (key.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace && value1.Length > 0)
        {
            value1 = value1.Substring(0, (value1.Length - 1));
            Console.Write("\b \b");
        }
    }
}
// Stops Receving Keys Once Enter is Pressed
while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.Enter);

Console.WriteLine();

//parsed here if entered correctly

Double x;
Double parsedVariable = 0;
if (Double.TryParse(value1, out x))
{
    Console.WriteLine("You have entered " + x);
    Console.Clear();

}
```

Comment: There is a specific reason to not use ReadLine instead?

Comment: What @Steve said.  You could just check if `Console.ReadLine` returns null, empty or whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

People make mistakes, and sometimes even purposely try to make the program fail. One of your jobs as a programmer is to write your code so that mistakes and maliciousness do not cause the program to fail.

You can't prevent the user from making a mistake. You can, however, write your code so that it's tolerant of mistakes.

In particular, the whole idea of trying to prevent the user from entering something he shouldn't enter is a whole lot harder and a lot less friendly than just letting the user enter *anything* and then checking it. For example, your code above that's ostensibly "helping" the user to enter a valid floating point number is actually a hindrance.

Imagine that the user has entered "78.369". But then he realizes that he was supposed to enter "0.78369". So he hits the Home key (what? Your editor doesn't support the Home key? Let's assume that it does, since it should), meaning to type "0.", and then arrow forward two spaces to delete the period. That's a perfectly reasonable thing to do, but your code won't let the user do it.

It's much more user-friendly, and easier to code, something that lets the user take advantage of all the editing features (such as they are) of the console, and then check the user's entire input. Something like:

```
string userInput;
double parsedValue;
bool valueIsGood;
do
{
    Console.Write("Enter the first value: ");
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
    userInput = userInput?.Trim(); // get rid of leading and trailing spaces
    valueIsGood = 
        string.IsNullOrEmpty(userInput) == false
        && double.TryParse(userInput, out parsedValue);
    if (!valueIsGood)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("You must enter a number.");
    }
while (!valueIsGood);
```